# Control of type 'ImageButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. I thought MVC didn't use this?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I thought one of the benefits of using ASP.Net MVC2 was the cleaner and more logical markup you could make for a webpage.

I'm creating the design of my master page and when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Control 'ctl00_ImageButton1' of type 'ImageButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

Here's the code:

```
<body>    
    <div id="headerarea">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/logo.png" PostBackUrl="~/Views/Home/Index.aspx" />
        <p><span class="salute"><strong>Hola.</strong></span> Inicie sesion para poder crear tus propios anuncios gratis! Eres nuevo? Empieza aqui.</p>
        <div id="topmenu">
            <img src="../../Content/categorybutton.png" alt="Nuestras categorias" />
            <p>Buscar en</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What should I do to fix this error? Any tips?

Comment: You need to learn more about ASP.Net MVC.  `/Views/Home/Index.aspx` is not a public URL.

Comment: Also, the relative path in your `<img>` will not usually work.  You should call `Url.Content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC does not use *any* `runat="server"` controls (except `asp:ContentPlaceHodler`s for master pages).

You should use raw HTML instead:

```
<input type="image" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/logo.png")" />
```

Note that HTML `<input>` tags must be inside a `<form>`.

Also note that `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx` is not a valid path for the client.

You probably want a simple hyperlink instead:

```
<a href="/">
    <img src=<%=Url.Content("~/Content/logo.png")" alt="Our Logo" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This image is the logo of my pet project website and I want to be able to click it and go back to the index website. I'd need to create a <form> with action to the index website and method of get. Is there a simple way to have a clickable image without a lot of code?

Comment: You're looking for a hyperlink.

Comment: A Hyperlink is just text, I need an image.

Comment: Hyperlinks can contain any tags you want.